# Em jQuery, como posso fazer uma seleção de um elemento usando "this", dentro de um que já estou selecionando

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tentei fazer assim:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#formulario").submit(function(){

    //Esse trecho não funciona
    $(this "input").each(function(){});

  });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Podes usar `$("input", this)` ou `$(this).find("input")`.

Exemplo:

```js
$('div').each(function() {
  $("input", this).val('teste'); // seta o value
  $(this).find("input").attr('disabled', false); // tira o disabled
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" disabled/>
</div>
```